# Exclude files from tar gzipping a directory in unix

Tags: unix, gzip, tar

I have a directory (`dir`) (with files and subdirectories):

```
ls -1 dir
plot.pdf
subdir.1
subdir.2
obj.RDS
```

And then `ls -1` for either `subdir.1` or `subdir.2`:

```
plot.pdf
PC.pdf
results.csv
de.pdf
de.csv
de.RDS
```

I would like to `tar` and `gzip` dir (in `unix`) and I'd like to exclude all `RDS` files (the the level right below `dir` and the ones in its subdirectories).

What's the easiest way to achieve that? Perhaps in a one liner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
find dir -type f -not -name '*.RDS' -print0 | 
              tar --null -T- -czf TARGET.tgz
```

should do it.

First, `find` finds the files, and then `tar` accepts the list via `-T-` (= `--files-from /dev/stdin`).

`-print0` on `find` combined wth `--null` on tar protect from weird filenames.

`-czf` == Create gZipped File

You can add `v` to get verbose output.

To later inspect the contents, you can do:

```
tar tf TARGET.tgz
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tar --exclude=*.RDS -Jcf outputball.tar  dir_to_compress
```

this will ignore *.RDS  across any dir or subdirs

decompress using

```
tar -xvf outputball.tar
```