# find: Exclude files with the same name based on their depth in a directory

Tags: linux, find

I have a free of files like this:

```
root_dir
|
-- dir1
     |
     -- file.ext
     -- misc.txt
     subdir
        |
        -- file.ext
        -- rest.ext
|
-- dir2
     |
     -- file.ext
     -- misc.txt
     subdir
        |
        -- file.ext
        -- rest.ext
```

and I want to compress the following subset of it:

```
root_dir
|
-- dir1
     |
     -- misc.txt
     subdir
        |
        -- file.ext
        -- rest.ext
|
-- dir2
     |
     -- misc.txt
     subdir
        |
        -- file.ext
        -- rest.ext
```

My plan is to first get a list of the files, and then pipe them to gzip or tar. The files in `dir1` and `dir2` have the same name (but different content). Yet, the problematic part is that `file.ext` in `dir*` and `subdir` have the same name, which makes filtering the files based on the names a bit tricky.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42989171/exclude-files-from-tar-gzipping-a-directory-in-unix), I have tried the following in the `root_dir`

```
find -type -f -not -name *misc.txt*
```

but, expectedly, it finds the `file.ext` at the depth one as well. Is there a way to exclude these depth-1 `file.ext`s from the `find` ouput?

**Notes**

- the extentions are dummy and represent a bunch of files with various types
- I have hundreds of `dir1` and `dir2`
- each `dir*` is very large and its not efficient to compress all first, and then remove the first level `file.ext`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sh
find . -type f -not -regex '\./[^/]+/file\.ext'
```

It will discard anything that match the regex. Here a direct subdirectory containing the file `file.ext`.

The regex is run to the whole path.

- `\.` means starts with a `.`
- `[^/]+` means a bunch of characters not containing a `/`
- `file\.ext` means `file.ext`